# Mysqli_fetch_row error

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y me he quedado estancado acá, el error es el siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\scripts\funciones.php on line 29

Y aca dejo mi función:

```
function validarLogin($usuario, $clave){

    global $conexion;
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."''  AND clave = '".$clave."'";
    $respuesta= mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

if ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($respuesta) ) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        return true;
    }
    return false;


 }
```

---

Buenas tardes, gracias por el feedback, el error se solvento, ahora tengo este script que me sirve como puente para acceder al panel de usuario, introduzco el usuario y la clave correctos, y aun me dice que son incorrectos, ademas de mostrar la pagina en blanco

alert('Los datos ingresados son incorrectos')
    location.href="../index.php";

Comment: Un posible error que tienes una comilla `'` de más al final en tu sentencia `'".$usuario."''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te está **diciendo el error** es que el método `mysqli_fetch_row()` espera al **menos 1 resultado** para poder **recorrer**, pero lo que está devolviendo `$respuesta` es `false`, ya que **la consulta no devuelve ningún registro**.

Para preveer esto es **mejor** que utilices una sintaxis como la siguiente:

```
function validarLogin($usuario, $clave){
    
        global $conexion;
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."''  AND clave = '".$clave."'";
         if ($respuesta= mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)) {
            while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($respuesta)) {
               session_start();
               $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
               return true;
            }
         mysqli_free_result($resultado);
         } else {
         return false;
        }
}
```

Donde el primer `if` está condicionando si el resultado de la consulta es `true` continuara con el `mysqli_fetch_row` y sino `return false;`

## Aclaración Importante:

Si estás **utilizando esta función** para **validar los datos ingresados** en un `login`, lo que estás teniendo es **serios riesgos de inyección de código**, utilizando la variable `$consulta` para **almacenar la consulta SQL concatenando los parámetros de búsqueda**.

> Puedes leer más sobre SQL Injection: [PHP: Inyección de SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php), [Respuesta de SOes sobre SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/6104382)

Esto puedes prevenirlo, modificando el código para utilizar `prepared-statement` y `parameters`.

```
function validarLogin($usuario, $clave){
    
        global $conexion;
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND clave = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $clave);

        $stmt->execute();

        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {         
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta. Cuando la consulta no devuelve ningún registro, `mysqli_query` no devuelve false sino un mysqli_result con 0 registros, y el usuario no recibiría ningún error. El problema es otro.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546345/6104382 https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546363/6104382

Al error original del OP responde mi pregunta, sobre el mysqli_fetch_error, no veo cual otro problema es.

Comment: esas respuestas son de hace 7+ años y son "incorrectas" (puede que sea porque con el tiempo quedaron mal, al menos la de Raveren, mientras que la de Sean apunta a que la consulta tiene errores al hacer joins). Además, esa pregunta está marcada como duplicada de otra en la que las respuestas principales dicen eso: hay errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Alvaro te agradezco la ayuda, editaré mi respuesta. Saludos y felices fiestas.

Answer (score 0):

El error que recibes es éste:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\scripts\funciones.php on line 29

Que quiere decir que el primer parámetro que le pasas a `mysqli_fetch_row` es incorrecto porque debería ser un `mysqli_result` pero realmente es un booleano (y FALSE para ser más específicos aunque no lo diga el error).

Este error ocurre porque el `$respuesta` (el resultado de `mysqli_query`) es un valor booleano. Esto ocurre porque la respuesta de `mysqli_query` fue FALSE que, como se especifica en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) solo ocurre cuando hay un error:

> [mysqli::query - mysqli_query] Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query() retornará TRUE.

**Esto indica que hay un error en la consulta que realizaste** (p.e. un error de sintaxis o nombres de tablas/columnas incorrectas). En particular, y [como dice D.Bulten en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83203/mysqli-fetch-row-error/83210?noredirect=1#comment153741_83203), el problema es que hay las comillas están mal en la consulta:

```
"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."''  AND clave = '".$clave."'"
                                                      ^ esta comilla está de más
```

Debería ser de este otro modo:

```
"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'  AND clave = '".$clave."'"
```

Además, [como bien indica Agustin M. en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83210/250), deberías usar métodos más seguros a la hora de realizar consultas en la base de datos: consultas parametrizadas en lugar de concatenación de cadenas que pueden causar errores (por ejemplo si el nombre de usuario contiene una comilla simple) y problemas graves de seguridad (como la inyección SQL).